Running Renovate CI on Another Branch
I am using Renovate CI in my repository named "repository-1". This repository contains renovate.json and renovate-config.js and the main branch is dev, my branch is called my-branch . In the repository that codes Renovate, named .github, I created a branch an did some modifications in renovate-config.json. The name of this branch is renovate-1095 and the name of the main branch is dev.
My goal is to use Renovate from repository-1, but the Renovate version with renovate-1095 instead of dev. Therefore, I wish to test renovate without having the need to create a PR and merge it into main everytime.
I tried to use baseBranches and useBaseBranchConfig as stated in https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#usebasebranchconfig in renovate-config.js and renovate.json in the reposiotry where I used Renovate. I included the name of the branch in the renovate repository, but I am still unable to run the renovate version of my new branch.
I hope this is clear. If not, please let me know what details are needed
